# Python filter array objects

Tags: python, arrays, database, sorting, columnsorting

I pull the following data from a Database

EventTime  UserID  SubAddr

2018-05-04 16:47:56.000 113 1
2018-05-04 16:48:45.000 113 2
2018-05-04 16:49:17.000 113 1
2018-05-04 16:49:27.000 113 2
2018-05-04 16:49:48.000 113 1
2018-05-04 16:49:57.000 113 2
2018-05-04 16:50:15.000 113 1
2018-05-04 16:51:01.000 113 2
2018-05-04 16:51:23.000 113 1
2018-05-04 16:51:33.000 113 2
2018-05-07 15:42:13.000 114 1
2018-05-07 15:42:16.000 114 1
2018-05-07 15:42:26.000 114 1
2018-05-07 15:42:35.000 114 2
2018-05-07 15:42:43.000 114 2
2018-05-07 15:42:54.000 114 1
2018-05-07 15:43:02.000 114 1
2018-05-07 15:43:11.000 114 2
2018-05-07 15:43:20.000 114 2
2018-05-07 15:43:35.000 114 1
2018-05-07 15:43:42.000 114 1
2018-05-07 15:43:51.000 114 2
2018-05-07 15:43:58.000 114 2

I want it to remove all the objects from the array( or create a new array that looks like this :

EventTime  UserID  SubAddr

2018-05-04 16:47:56.000 113 1
2018-05-04 16:48:45.000 113 2
2018-05-04 16:49:17.000 113 1
2018-05-04 16:49:27.000 113 2
2018-05-04 16:49:48.000 113 1
2018-05-04 16:49:57.000 113 2
2018-05-04 16:50:15.000 113 1
2018-05-04 16:51:01.000 113 2
2018-05-04 16:51:23.000 113 1
2018-05-04 16:51:33.000 113 2
2018-05-07 15:42:13.000 114 1
2018-05-07 15:42:35.000 114 2
2018-05-07 15:42:54.000 114 1
2018-05-07 15:43:11.000 114 2
2018-05-07 15:43:35.000 114 1
2018-05-07 15:43:51.000 114 2

Basicly I want it to remove all the objects when there are multiple objects following eachother where there the SubAddr is the same I only want it to grab the first one. SubAddr is always 1 or 2. Subaddr an action triggerd by the user.

I don't want to do this in SQL because I want to perform other tasks on the same array as well.

Each row of data is put in an object and this object is added to an array. I want it to filter this data in Python3

EDIT: My object looks like this

```
class Events:
def __init__(self, id, EventTime, Address, SubAddr, UserId):
    self.id = id
    self.EventTime = EventTime
    self.Address = Address
    self.SubAddr = SubAddr
    self.UserId = UserId
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
In [1]: string = '''2018-05-04 16:47:56.000 113 1
   ...: 2018-05-04 16:48:45.000 113 2
   ...: 2018-05-04 16:49:17.000 113 1
   ...: 2018-05-04 16:49:27.000 113 2
   ...: 2018-05-04 16:49:48.000 113 1
   ...: 2018-05-04 16:49:57.000 113 2
   ...: 2018-05-04 16:50:15.000 113 1
   ...: 2018-05-04 16:51:01.000 113 2
   ...: 2018-05-04 16:51:23.000 113 1
   ...: 2018-05-04 16:51:33.000 113 2
   ...: 2018-05-07 15:42:13.000 114 1
   ...: 2018-05-07 15:42:16.000 114 1
   ...: 2018-05-07 15:42:26.000 114 1
   ...: 2018-05-07 15:42:35.000 114 2
   ...: 2018-05-07 15:42:43.000 114 2
   ...: 2018-05-07 15:42:54.000 114 1
   ...: 2018-05-07 15:43:02.000 114 1
   ...: 2018-05-07 15:43:11.000 114 2
   ...: 2018-05-07 15:43:20.000 114 2
   ...: 2018-05-07 15:43:35.000 114 1
   ...: 2018-05-07 15:43:42.000 114 1
   ...: 2018-05-07 15:43:51.000 114 2
   ...: 2018-05-07 15:43:58.000 114 2'''

In [2]: data = string.splitlines()

In [3]: data
Out[3]: 
['2018-05-04 16:47:56.000 113 1',
 '2018-05-04 16:48:45.000 113 2',
 '2018-05-04 16:49:17.000 113 1',
 '2018-05-04 16:49:27.000 113 2',
 '2018-05-04 16:49:48.000 113 1',
 '2018-05-04 16:49:57.000 113 2',
 '2018-05-04 16:50:15.000 113 1',
 '2018-05-04 16:51:01.000 113 2',
 '2018-05-04 16:51:23.000 113 1',
 '2018-05-04 16:51:33.000 113 2',
 '2018-05-07 15:42:13.000 114 1',
 '2018-05-07 15:42:16.000 114 1',
 '2018-05-07 15:42:26.000 114 1',
 '2018-05-07 15:42:35.000 114 2',
 '2018-05-07 15:42:43.000 114 2',
 '2018-05-07 15:42:54.000 114 1',
 '2018-05-07 15:43:02.000 114 1',
 '2018-05-07 15:43:11.000 114 2',
 '2018-05-07 15:43:20.000 114 2',
 '2018-05-07 15:43:35.000 114 1',
 '2018-05-07 15:43:42.000 114 1',
 '2018-05-07 15:43:51.000 114 2',
 '2018-05-07 15:43:58.000 114 2']

In [11]: datas = list(map(lambda s: s.rsplit(' ', 2), data))

In [12]: datas
Out[12]: 
[['2018-05-04 16:47:56.000', '113', '1'],
 ['2018-05-04 16:48:45.000', '113', '2'],
 ['2018-05-04 16:49:17.000', '113', '1'],
 ['2018-05-04 16:49:27.000', '113', '2'],
 ['2018-05-04 16:49:48.000', '113', '1'],
 ['2018-05-04 16:49:57.000', '113', '2'],
 ['2018-05-04 16:50:15.000', '113', '1'],
 ['2018-05-04 16:51:01.000', '113', '2'],
 ['2018-05-04 16:51:23.000', '113', '1'],
 ['2018-05-04 16:51:33.000', '113', '2'],
 ['2018-05-07 15:42:13.000', '114', '1'],
 ['2018-05-07 15:42:16.000', '114', '1'],
 ['2018-05-07 15:42:26.000', '114', '1'],
 ['2018-05-07 15:42:35.000', '114', '2'],
 ['2018-05-07 15:42:43.000', '114', '2'],
 ['2018-05-07 15:42:54.000', '114', '1'],
 ['2018-05-07 15:43:02.000', '114', '1'],
 ['2018-05-07 15:43:11.000', '114', '2'],
 ['2018-05-07 15:43:20.000', '114', '2'],
 ['2018-05-07 15:43:35.000', '114', '1'],
 ['2018-05-07 15:43:42.000', '114', '1'],
 ['2018-05-07 15:43:51.000', '114', '2'],
 ['2018-05-07 15:43:58.000', '114', '2']]


In [20]: l = [datas[0]]

In [21]: prev = datas[0][2]

In [22]: for i, j, k in datas[1:]:
    ...:     if prev == k:
    ...:         continue
    ...:     l.append([i, j, k])
    ...:     prev = k
    ...:     

In [23]: l
Out[23]: 
[['2018-05-04 16:47:56.000', '113', '1'],
 ['2018-05-04 16:48:45.000', '113', '2'],
 ['2018-05-04 16:49:17.000', '113', '1'],
 ['2018-05-04 16:49:27.000', '113', '2'],
 ['2018-05-04 16:49:48.000', '113', '1'],
 ['2018-05-04 16:49:57.000', '113', '2'],
 ['2018-05-04 16:50:15.000', '113', '1'],
 ['2018-05-04 16:51:01.000', '113', '2'],
 ['2018-05-04 16:51:23.000', '113', '1'],
 ['2018-05-04 16:51:33.000', '113', '2'],
 ['2018-05-07 15:42:13.000', '114', '1'],
 ['2018-05-07 15:42:35.000', '114', '2'],
 ['2018-05-07 15:42:54.000', '114', '1'],
 ['2018-05-07 15:43:11.000', '114', '2'],
 ['2018-05-07 15:43:35.000', '114', '1'],
 ['2018-05-07 15:43:51.000', '114', '2']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    inp_db_lst = ['2018-05-04 16:47:56.000 113 1','2018-05-04 16:48:45.000 113 2','2018-05-04 16:49:17.000 113 1','2018-05-04 16:49:27.000 113 2','2018-05-04 16:49:48.000 113 1','2018-05-04 16:49:57.000 113 2','2018-05-04 16:50:15.000 113 1','2018-05-04 16:51:01.000 113 2','2018-05-04 16:51:23.000 113 1','2018-05-04 16:51:33.000 113 2','2018-05-07 15:42:13.000 114 1','2018-05-07 15:42:16.000 114 1','2018-05-07 15:42:26.000 114 1','2018-05-07 15:42:35.000 114 2','2018-05-07 15:42:43.000 114 2','2018-05-07 15:42:54.000 114 1','2018-05-07 15:43:02.000 114 1','2018-05-07 15:43:11.000 114 2','2018-05-07 15:43:20.000 114 2','2018-05-07 15:43:35.000 114 1','2018-05-07 15:43:42.000 114 1','2018-05-07 15:43:51.000 114 2','2018-05-07 15:43:58.000 114 2']
    new_res_lst = []
    temp = ''
    for val_str in inp_db_lst:
        if val_str.split()[-1] != temp:
            new_res_lst.append(val_str)
        temp = val_str.split()[-1]
    print new_res_lst

    Result:['2018-05-04 16:47:56.000 113 1', '2018-05-04 16:48:45.000 113 2', '2018-05-04 16:49:17.000 113 1', '2018-05-04 16:49:27.000 113 2', '2018-05-04 16:49:48.000 113 1', '2018-05-04 16:49:57.000 113 2', '2018-05-04 16:50:15.000 113 1', '2018-05-04 16:51:01.000 113 2', '2018-05-04 16:51:23.000 113 1', '2018-05-04 16:51:33.000 113 2', '2018-05-07 15:42:13.000 114 1', '2018-05-07 15:42:35.000 114 2', '2018-05-07 15:42:54.000 114 1', '2018-05-07 15:43:11.000 114 2', '2018-05-07 15:43:35.000 114 1', '2018-05-07 15:43:51.000 114 2']
```

Comment: I added the layout for the object which I store all the variables in. How would this look if it got the data from the object out the array?

Comment: i didn't get your input db data format actually,Better make db data in a list rather than passing each as a objects to constructor

Comment: So basicly have a list for Eventtime, UserId and a list for SubAddr